# Can an adjective be used in a plural form

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, adjectives, british-english

As we know, an adjective modifies a noun and sometimes a noun also modifies a noun and works as an adjective. But my question is, can an adjective or a noun be used in a plural form to modify a noun in English. I have asked this as I read it on a news website.

> **On the news website:**
>
> "These women will also look for younger men. And then you start seeing
>   men in the **streets** fighting."
>
> As per my opinion it should have been used:
>
> "These women will also look for younger men. And then you start seeing
>   men in the **street** fighting."

Comment: I think the issue here is simply the argument between using the singular "street" i.e. the proverbial/average street, versus the more literal "streets" i.e. the streets in which they were fighting.

Comment: Where's adjective? Understand this - *I saw him in the room crying.* :) *room* is a noun there and the verb *crying* refers to the man in the room. Am I missing something?

Comment: The phrase *men in the streets* here is ***not*** the plural of the idiom *man in the street*, if that's what you are confused about. The plural of *man in the street* would be *men in the street*. This news article is talking about *men* who happen to be in the *streets* of some city.

Comment: Adjectives are never plural.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, the sentence

> These women will also look for younger men. And then you start seeing
>   men **in the streets** fighting.

could be rephrased as:

> These women will also look for younger men. And then you start seeing
>   men fighting **in the streets**.

The word *streets* here is not being used as an 'adjectivized noun'. The writer does not want to stress that the men are engaged in 'street-fighting', he wants to say that a passer-by will start noticing fighting men now and then in the streets.

Had the author wanted to say what you thought he wanted, he would have written, for instance:

> .. And then you start seeing men engaged in **street** fights.

A noun, when used in the adjective role, cannot assume the plural form. Some English nouns, however, look as if they are in the plural: *news, athletics*, although they are not really. Hence, we have *a news reporter*, *an athletics coach* - these may mislead a non-native speaker sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Nominal or proper adjectives resist the plural ending to the point that when pluralized temporal phrases are used adjectivally, they lose the plural ending:

> a three-day hike
>
> a five-mile run
>
> a 20 year-old woman

Also, sometimes plain adjectives are used to refer to people (plural), in which case they are definite and collective:

> feeding the hungry
>
> healing the sick
>
> helping the poor